# Knockout, collection property becomes null when I try and remove one item from it if it has more than one item in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Really strange knockout error I am having. It's a pretty complex scenario so please see this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/yx8dkLnc/

Essentially I have a double nested collection, the first collection `FishMeasurements` contains a collection of objects which have the species information associated with it, and a collection of `Measurements` which hold all measurements associated with that species.

Now when I try and remove items from the nested collection in this HTML:

```
<!-- ko foreach: FishMeasurements() -->
                <h3><span data-bind="text: SpeciesName"></span><span data-bind="text: SpeciesId" style="display: none;"></span></h3>
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Length</th>
                            <th>Count</th>
                            <th>Weight</th>
                            <th>Fish Id</th>
                            <th>&nbsp;</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Measurements()">
                        <tr>
                            <td><span data-bind="text: LengthInMillimeters"></span></td>
                            <td><span data-bind="text: Count"></span></td>
                            <td><span data-bind="text: WeightInPounds"></span></td>
                            <td><span data-bind="text: FishCode"></span></td>
                            <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: function() { $root.removeMeasurement($data, $index); }">Remove</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            <!-- /ko -->
```

The remove measurement function doesn't work when the `Measurements` collection has more than one object. I click the remove link, and it throws an error that says:

> VM617:163 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Measurements' of null(…)

The strange thing about this is, if I only add one item to the Measurements collection, the delete button work fine, but as soon as I add multiple measurements, if I click remove on any item in the table but the first row, this error is generated. However, if I click the first item in the table per species, there is no error and all records are removed!

Something tells me its treating Measurements like one object instead of a collection, because it only works on index 0. But I'm not sure because in console I am able to type:

```
mappedModel.FishMeasurements()[0].Measurements()[1]
```

And get a full ko_mapping object returned, so it's not null. But for some reason when I click the remove, it is null. As long as there is only one measurement per species, clicking remove works fine, as soon as there are more it breaks.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look at the update on my answer. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `addMeasurement` for the first time `speciesId`, `speciesName` are getting defined because `fishMeasurementBySpecies === undefined` and therefore when you remove the first item you have a valid `measurement.SpeciesId()` as a parameter inside `removeMeasurement` function but for the second time and more since `fishMeasurementBySpecies` is not `undefined` anymore then `speciesId`, `speciesName` never get set and then when`removeMeasurement`is called,`measurement.SpeciesId()` is null.

In order to make your model works, you need to apply below changes.

define  `var speciesId = mappedModel.SelectedSpecies();` before your if statment

```
var speciesId = mappedModel.SelectedSpecies();
if (fishMeasurementBySpecies === undefined || fishMeasurementBySpecies === null) {
```

Put `()` for `Measurements` inside removeMeasurement function where you want to get the length

```
if(fishMeasurementBySpecies.Measurements().length === 0)
```

Below I provide you an example of what you want to do by using manual view model instead of using `mapping` plugin.

---

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/118/

Your example :http://jsfiddle.net/yx8dkLnc/1/

VM:

```
var data = {
    "AvailableSpecies":
            [
            {"Id":"f57830b8-0766-4374-b481-82c04087415e","Name":"Alabama Shad"},    
          {"Id":"3787ce10-e61c-4f03-88a5-ff648bb55480","Name":"Alewife"},{"Id":"e923214f-4974-4663-9158-d6979ce637f1","Name":"All Sunfish Spp Ex Bass And Crappie"}          ],
        "SelectedSpecies": null,  "CountToAdd":0,"LengthToAdd":0,"WeightToAdd":0,"GenerateFishCode":false,"FishMeasurements":[]
};
function AppViewModel(){
   var self = this;
   self.AvailableSpecies = ko.observableArray(data.AvailableSpecies);
   self.SelectedSpecies = ko.observable();
   self.CountToAdd = ko.observable();
   self.LengthToAdd = ko.observable();
   self.WeightToAdd = ko.observable();
   self.FishCode = ko.observable();
   self.FishMeasurements = ko.observableArray([]);

   self.addMeasurement = function(item) {
     var SpeciesExists = false;

     ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.FishMeasurements(), function (item) {
       if(item.SpeciesId() == self.SelectedSpecies().Id) {
         var len = item.Measurements().length;
         // you may have a better way to generate a unique Id if an item is removed 
         while(item.Measurements().findIndex(x => x.Id() === len) > 0){
            len++;
         }
         item.Measurements.push(new MeasurementsViewModel({LengthInMillimeters:self.LengthToAdd(),
                                                           Count:self.CountToAdd(),
                                                           WeightInPounds:self.WeightToAdd(),
                                                           FishCode:self.FishCode(),
                                                           Id:len ++,
                                                           ParentId:self.SelectedSpecies().Id
                                                          })
                               );
         SpeciesExists = true;
       }
     });
     if(!SpeciesExists){
       self.FishMeasurements.push(new FishMeasurementsViewModel({SpeciesName:self.SelectedSpecies().Name,
                                                                 SpeciesId:self.SelectedSpecies().Id,
                                                                 Measurements:[{LengthInMillimeters:self.LengthToAdd(),
                                                                                Count:self.CountToAdd(),
                                                                                WeightInPounds:self.WeightToAdd(),
                                                                                FishCode:self.FishCode(),
                                                                                Id:1}]
                                                                })
                                 );
     }
   }
   self.removeMeasurement = function(data){
       ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.FishMeasurements(), function (item) {
            if(item && item.SpeciesId() == data.ParentId()) {
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(item.Measurements(), function (subItem) {
              if(subItem && subItem.Id() == data.Id()) {
                                item.Measurements.remove(subItem);
              }
            });
          }
          if(item && item.Measurements().length == 0){
             self.FishMeasurements.remove(item);
          }
       });
   }
 }
  var FishMeasurementsViewModel = function(data){
   var self = this;
   self.SpeciesName = ko.observable(data.SpeciesName);
   self.SpeciesId = ko.observable(data.SpeciesId);
   self.Measurements = ko.observableArray($.map(data.Measurements, function (item) {
     return new MeasurementsViewModel(item,self.SpeciesId());
   }));

 }
 var MeasurementsViewModel = function(data,parentId){
   var self = this;
   self.LengthInMillimeters = ko.observable(data.LengthInMillimeters);
   self.Count = ko.observable(data.Count);
   self.WeightInPounds = ko.observable(data.WeightInPounds);
   self.FishCode = ko.observable(data.FishCode);
   self.Id = ko.observable(data.Id);
   self.ParentId = ko.observable(parentId ? parentId : data.ParentId);
 }

var viewModel = new AppViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: Awesome, makes sense now that you found it, was hard to notice in my mess of JS =/.